# Is there a more fancy name for a "kitchen hole"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does English have a specific word for a hole between the kitchen and the living room that is used to get food directly to the dining table?

German has the nice *Durchreiche*, which approximately translates to *hand-through*. I am ideally looking for a nice translation of that word.

[image: kitchen hole]

Comment: What, "kitchen hole" isn't fancy enough for you? Some people are *so* hard to please.

Comment: @Robusto it contrasts nicely with [Car hole](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Made-up_words#Car_Hole) :)

Comment: @Pekka: Hahaha. And isn't Moe the same guy who promised to buy his girlfriend "a steak the size of a toilet seat"?

Comment: @Robusto hahaha, yes he is!

Comment: I clicked this question wondering what in the world a "kitchen hole" could be.

Comment: As this is most commonly used for communicating with guests to find out what they would like for dessert, we call it the "pie-hole", or "cake-hole", depending on what's on the menu.

Comment: Other people seem to have more elegant (or more specific) substitutions, but I have always just called it a 'window'.

Comment: @intuited, you might have to explain that one in some contexts. I (native en-gb speaker) understand "pie-hole" and "cake-hole" as "mouth", most commonly encountered following the words "Shut your".

Comment: @Peter Taylor: We use our mouths to communicate with guests to find out what they would like for dessert.

Comment: We just called ours a hatch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is also called a  [**serving hatch**](http://www.cartoonstock.com/directory/s/serving_hatch.asp).

> An opening in a wall at window height
>   for the purpose of serving food or
>   other items.
>
> *The cook passed the dishes through the serving hatch.*

from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hatch)

Answer (score 12):

I usually hear it called a **[kitchen pass-through](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=Kitchen+Pass+Through&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1241&bih=807)**.

Comment: Or just "pass-through". *Google* [ [define pass-through](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+pass-through) ] gives: “an opening that resembles a window between two rooms (especially a shelved opening between a kitchen and dining room that is used to pass dishes)”, citing *[WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn)*.

Answer (score 4):

In restaurants, I've heard that area is referred to as the pass and that is what we call it in our house.

Answer (score 3):

I've known it to be called a breakfast-bar.

A similar feature is a dumb-waiter, which is used to move crockery and food between different levels especially in hotels.

Comment: A breakfast bar is something completely different This is a breakfast bar. http://www.summerplace406.com/Pictures/Kitchen_Breakfast_BarN.jpg

Comment: @Ralph: It looks like some serving hatches can double as [breakfast bars](http://www.tuscanyvillasredding.com/images/homes/florence/breakfast%20bar%202.jpg), including the one pictured above. It's set with place mats and I think it shows the top of a stool.

Answer (score 1):

In French, it is known as a *passe-plat*, which is elegant and simple. It can also be translated simply as *hatch*, which might be better than serving hatch as any sentence employing it is likely to involve a *serving* context which would make it redundant.

Comment: In spanish is the same: pasa-platos (pasa=pass, platos=plates) http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=pasaplatos

Comment: Very nice, thanks for this! This question is in the context of a software naming decision and `passe-plat` is an interesting option.

Answer (score 1):

Not meaning to observe the obvious, but "service window" would be appropriate.